# Python: OpenCV findHomography inputs

Tags: python, opencv, homography

I am trying to find the homography matrix for two images `rgb` and `rotated` using opencv in Python:

```
print(rgb.shape, rotated.shape)
H = cv2.findHomography(rgb, rotated)
print(H)
```

And the error I get is

```
(1080, 1920, 3) (1080, 1920, 3)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-26874dc47f1f> in <module>()
      1 print(rgb.shape, rotated.shape)
----> 2 H = cv2.findHomography(rgb, rotated)
      3 print(H)

error: OpenCV(3.4.1) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\calib3d\src\fundam.cpp:372: error: (-5) The input arrays should be 2D or 3D point sets in function cv::findHomography
```

I also tried with `cv2.findHomography(rgb[:,:,0], rotated[:,:,0])` to see if the channels or channel ordering is causing any problem, but it's not working for even 2D matrix.

**How should the input be?**

Comment: [cv2.findHomography](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga4abc2ece9fab9398f2e560d53c8c9780) takes points (of type CV_32F) as inputs, it doesn't take pixel values.

Comment: You're passing the image, you're supposed to pass 2 arrays of coordinates, as in I have these points in image 1, and I have points in image 2 what is the homography matrix to transform the points from image 1 to image 2

Comment: You should follow the [tutorial](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_feature_homography/py_feature_homography.html#feature-homography) to understand what you're supposed to do

Comment: ahh.., just misunderstood that `findHomography()` does sift inside of it when given the images :/ my bad. @EdChum tutorial helps :) thanks

Comment: heads up this [tutorial](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_feature_homography/py_feature_homography.html#feature-homography) is super old, and expect to be bombarded with exceptions

Comment: Here's the updated link to the [tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d1/de0/tutorial_py_feature_homography.html) for Python 3 and opencv 3.4.1, just in case anyone wanted

Comment: @SaravanabalagiRamachandran OpenCV tutorial is [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/dff/tutorial_feature_homography.html) for features matching and homography estimation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cv2.findHomography()` doesn't take in two images and return `H`.

If you need to find `H` for two RGB images as np.arrays:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

def findHomography(img1, img2):

    # define constants
    MIN_MATCH_COUNT = 10
    MIN_DIST_THRESHOLD = 0.7
    RANSAC_REPROJ_THRESHOLD = 5.0

    # Initiate SIFT detector
    sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()

    # find the keypoints and descriptors with SIFT
    kp1, des1 = sift.detectAndCompute(img1, None)
    kp2, des2 = sift.detectAndCompute(img2, None)

    # find matches
    FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE = 1
    index_params = dict(algorithm=FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE, trees=5)
    search_params = dict(checks=50)

    flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params, search_params)
    matches = flann.knnMatch(des1, des2, k=2)

    # store all the good matches as per Lowe's ratio test.
    good = []
    for m, n in matches:
        if m.distance < MIN_DIST_THRESHOLD * n.distance:
            good.append(m)


    if len(good) > MIN_MATCH_COUNT:
        src_pts = np.float32([kp1[m.queryIdx].pt for m in good]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)
        dst_pts = np.float32([kp2[m.trainIdx].pt for m in good]).reshape(-1, 1, 2)

        H, _ = cv2.findHomography(src_pts, dst_pts, cv2.RANSAC, RANSAC_REPROJ_THRESHOLD)
        return H

    else: raise Exception("Not enough matches are found - {}/{}".format(len(good), MIN_MATCH_COUNT))
```

Note:

- Tested on `Python 3` and `OpenCV 3.4`
- You need `opencv-contrib-python` package because `SIFT` has patent issues and has been removed from `opencv-python`
- This gives the H matrix for transforming `img1` and overlap it on `img2`. If you're wondering how to do this, it's [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50949106/3125070)